# Save and access file from shared drive

Tags: sql, iis, active-directory, directory

I am running a file upload process to upload files to a db. The web server and the SQL server are different machines. I am attempting to use an SQL OPENROWSET to upload an excel file, but I cannot determine how to get the file onto the other machine. Is there a way to set up a shared drive that the web server can save a file to and the SQL server can access? We have a local network set up with Active Directory.

For Example:

WebServer - Shared drive on web server under C:/inetpub/webpage/fileImport

SQLServer - Will log in with sql auth using USERID and PASSWD. Needs to access webserver shared drive.

What user do I share the drive on web server with so that the sql auth user will be able to access it when I run the OPENROWSET?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the OPENROWSET means that SQL qill access files using the service account. This account must be used to access share drive, as stated here [Using SQL Credential to Open a file with OpenRowSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613475/using-sql-credential-to-open-a-file-with-openrowset).

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying the same thing by uploading the file in FTP and trying to access it. But i didn't get any progress from last 2 weeks.

And i had found may other alternatives like coping the files in another server and share the folder with out user name & password. then we can able to access it by giving the 
\\folder\filename

If u get any other alternative plz share...

Comment: I've been looking into SQL Credentials. Have you looked into that? Apparently they are used for accessing elements outside of the SQL Server itself, but I cannot find the syntax to use it with OPENROWSET. WITH CREDENTIAL throws an error.

Comment: Check the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613475/using-sql-credential-to-open-a-file-with-openrowset. I reposted when I had more information and more attempts. Someone was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a new user that has access to the user group iis_users, and then give them security access to the file drive itself.

The same should be done to the DB server, and on the drive folder security the other user will need read/write/Modify permissions.

So it will look like:

(WebHost) ---- (Shared) ---- (DBHost)

*-------***

Well, you would setup the folder on the SQLServer. 
Create a secure user on the SQL machine.
Make the folder shared (with modify rights for the secure user)
Map the Network drive on the Windows machine, using the secure user to access it.

Your main user on the SQLServer should then be able to openrowset from the local folder, whilst the IIS Server is remotely accessing it.

Comment: Could you outline these steps in more detail please? Do I great a new user on the SQL server? Do I create it on the windows machine? Does this involve an SQL Credential?

Comment: Well, you would setup the folder on the SQLServer. Make the folder shared.